# Recursive timed XHR to fill a collection

Tags: backbone.js, closures, backbone-relational

For one of my backbone project (in which i cannot implement REST/sync), i need to refresh a backbone collection (using backbone relational as model, if it matters ?) every X seconds.

What i've been doing is implement a function like this :

```js
refresh: function(){
    var self = this;

    // clears timeout
    self.timeoutRefresh && clearTimeout(self.timeoutRefresh);

    // aborts request if running
    self.xhrRefresh && self.xhrRefresh.abort();

    // do request
    self.xhrRefresh = self.options.myfunction.call(self, {}, function (data) {

        self.mycollection.set(data);

        // call it again in 5 seconds
        self.timeoutRefresh = _.delay(function(){
            self.refresh.call(self);
        }, 5 * 1000);
    });
},
```

The problem is that this block of code seems to be guilty of a big memory leak in my application.

Can it be a closure problem with the `self` variable ?

Should i then do the recursive call this way ?

```js
self.timeoutRefresh = _.delay(function(context){
    context.refresh.call(context);
}, 5 * 1000, self);
```

If not, where does it come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a lot of chrome debugging, i figured out backbone relational was never actually replacing my objects cause it is doing comparison over the id attribute which my objects didn't have (physically and logically).

I ended up calculating a md5 hash from the different meaningful properties of my object and using it as id so backbone relational would know it shouldn't consider the object as a new one.

Conclusion, it's not a closure problem as chrome garbage collector does its thing well.

NB: [Backbone debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger/bhljhndlimiafopmmhjlgfpnnchjjbhd) helped me a lot finding where the problem came from.